# Drupal \Drupal\user\Entity\User how retrieve property

Tags: drupal

i come from ES6 and need to do something in one Drupal 8 site.
Basically I try to get some value from the current logged user object.

...i try any possible method but nothing good.

by this snippet of code i can dump($userx) variable, i need to parse

```
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser();
$uid = $userCurrent->id();
$userx = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadByProperties([
'uid' => '13465'
]);
dump($userx);
outpup see picture


$cf = $userx->get('field_codice_fiscale_user')->getvalue()[0]['value'];
dump($cf);
otput NULL
```

Results output
[image]

i need the value of

```
protected values

 field_cv_codice_fiscale
    
    x-default => array (1)

      0 => array (1)

        value => string (16) "DSSSLV83D67B35QV"
```

i tried:

```
  $cf = $userx->get('field_codice_fiscale_user')->getvalue()[0]['value'];
  again NULL
```

my goal is to have variable valorized by :

```
  'field_codice_fiscale_user' -> value;
```

after struglling two days i need to give up to drupal folly.

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the first code in your post, you are settings the variable `$userx`, but then trying to get the field value of `$userJ`.....? Try `$userx->get('field_cv_codice_fiscale')->value`

Comment: Thank you @2pha, no was a refuse, if you look at "I tried" notice was correct...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

as reported in the Drupal specification, entityTypeManager return objects array.

so the corect snippet is:

```
$userx = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->loadByProperties([
'uid' => $uid2 ]);
```

dpm($userx);

```
$cfx = $userx[$uid2];
```

now the variable $cfx contain objects (inpictures = '3465' objects).

we can access the object property by this way

```
if(isset($cfx->get('field_codice_fiscale_user')->getvalue()[0]['value'])) { 
 $cf = $cfx->get('field_codice_fiscale_user')->getvalue()[0]['value'];
} else { $cf = '';}
```

dmp($cf)

output

```
$scf = 'DSLL....'
```